# Eclipse slow typing

Tags: linux, eclipse, awesome-wm

I have eclipse running under awesome-wm. 
The program itself runs fine but keyboard input has a lag ~300ms which is really annoying.  Also scrolling with mouse is ok, but scrolling with PGup or PGdown or arrow keys is laggy, and when entering text the cursor blinks weirdly.

However, when I changed to window-maker or xfce wm everything works ok.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.5) (ArchLinux build 7.u51_2.4.5-1-i686)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Eclipse version
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the repeat rate. As far as I know individual desktop environment set their respective repeat rates. You can find the difference using the following in awesome and Xfce.

```
xset q | grep rate
```

You can set a suitable repeat rate using the following.

```
xset r rate 660 30
```

You can adjust the values to your convenience. For more details refer [here](http://intosimple.blogspot.in/2013/06/change-repeat-rate-in-awesome-wm.html).